# Anyone know why this MYSQL INSERT doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pilot", $con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (id, userid, date, plane, from, to, blocksoff, takeoff,
landing, blockson, flighttime, traveltime, tachobefore, tachoafter, tacho, 
hobbsbefore, hobbsafter, hobbs, landings) VALUES ('$nfid', '$nfuserid', 
'$nfdate', '$nfplane', '$nffrom', '$nfto', '$nfblocksoff', '$nftakeoff', 
'$nflanding', '$nfblockson', '$nfflighttime', '$nftraveltime', '$nftachobefore', 
'$nftachoafter', '$nftacho', '$nfhobbsbefore', '$nfhobbsafter', '$nfhobbs',
'$nflandings')";

mysql_query($sql);
```

there ain't nothing wrong with the $sql, it seems like it just wont query.. :(

```
id|userid=int(11)  
date=date  
plane|from|to=text  
blocksoff|takeoff|landing|blockson=time  
flighttime|traveltime|tachobefore|tachoafter|tacho|hobbsbefore|hobbsafter|hobbs|landings=double
```

all of the $ variables come from a textbox (if it matters)

Comment: Print $sql and paste it here!

Comment: Try to echo `$sql` and running it manually.  Also try chainging `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: P.S. Using `mysql_*` is discouraged. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: What does the _actual_ query look like? Does it run against the database if you try it manually? Is there an error from the database engine? Is there an error from the PHP engine? Is your code even getting to this code block or is something else stopping it? There is _so_ much debugging you could do...

Comment: Do any of the variables contain `'`?  Do you `mysql_real_escape_string` them?

Comment: mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, blocksoff, takeoff, landing, blockson, flighttime, traveltime, tachobe' at line 1
----------->>
echo $sql;
INSERT INTO logs (id, userid, date, plane, from, to, blocksoff, takeoff, landing, blockson, flighttime, traveltime, tachobefore, tachoafter, tacho, hobbsbefore, hobbsafter, hobbs, landings) VALUES ('7', '0', '2012-06-25', 'TF-GG', 'BIRK', 'BIRK', '13:37:00', '13:37:00', '13:37:00', '13:37:00', '0', ..x9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be some of the column names are MySql reserved words (especially `from` and `to`). Please escape them.

```
INSERT INTO logs (`id`, userid, date, plane, `from`, `to` ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always be checking for errors:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an open ended question....

Are any of your variables returning NULL values?  If you are trying to insert NULL into the database, and the database column isn't set to accept NULL values, that could be causing an error.

You need to see what the query is actually doing.  If you have any single quotes or other invalid character from the textbox, that could be screwing you up.

Also, for your own personal improvement, look up PDO.  It helps you write much more secure queries through the use of prepared statements.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Pretty sure if you send `NULL` to a `NOT NULL` field, it'll just be converted (to `0` or `''`).

Comment: You're probably right; it's been a while since I've done queries like above.  I know it errors out on the PDO prepared statements that I use.